# How to check the default linked codec used by openCV-Python?

Tags: python, opencv, pycharm

I just came into the world of openCV and python, and I'm having a strange issue with opening the video stream. This is the code that I'm using:

```
import numpy
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('SampleVideo.mp4')
print(cap.isOpened())
while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This code can successfully open the video stream when i run it in terminal(windows command line) but not in Pycharm. This is the result of the run in Pycharm:

> False
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you all!

Codec: FFmpeg. OS: Windows 8.1. Python: 3.5.2. OpenCV: 3.1

Update Sep.27:

I noticed that the code runs successfully in IDLE, but not in PyCharm. Now I'm really confused.

I can also confirm that imread and imwrite works properly in PyCharm. So maybe it is the Codec that is not working? How to check my codec in OpenCV?

Update Sep.29:

Now I think I've ruled out the possibility that the terminal and PyCharm are using different interpreter. I really think it's somehow that the default codec is not linked in the PyCharm environment. **How do I check my default system codec either in OpenCV or Python?**

Comment: use the full path to the file

Comment: @Miki no that didn't help. I'm pretty sure that i put the file in the working directory. The i/o command on pictures (imread/write) works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved.

I solved it by purging everything, Pycharm, Python and all the packages. So obviously this issue came from some sort of dependency mess-up. Not really sure what it is, but purging is the way to go people.